# How could I validate my battery management schematic?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I drew a battery management system schematic based on this reference [project](https://mega.nz/folder/XToA2L6R#ojKWhIJW7fEtmMzVfTJz2g/folder/af5FCQrL) found from a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYrftE13UzE)
The reference schematic is this:
[image]

I tried to draw my own schematic and I have changed the original Q3, Q4, Q6, and Q7 [MOSFETs 2SK3919](https://mega.nz/folder/XToA2L6R#ojKWhIJW7fEtmMzVfTJz2g/folder/rGxDSY6R) for the [PSMN6R5-25YLC](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN6R5-25YLC.pdf) due to they are not available. I also changed the shunt resistor R25 and R26 (0R005) for the [CSRL3-0R001F8](https://riedon.com/media/pdf/CSRL.pdf)

My schematic is:

[image]

How could I simulate or validate my schematic before proceeding to route the pads in the PCB?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you reconsider. There are some great ICs out there for a 3S battery that are far simpler, guaranteed to work, have 1/10 as many components, and won't discharge your battery in a few days (which this circuit will). For example, consider the [TI BQ7790521PWR](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ77905/part-details/BQ7790521PWR).

Comment: thank you for your recommendations! Do you know about a reference project that uses the BQ7790521 IC?

Comment: The spec sheet has one.

Comment: Why don't you use an off-the-shelf 3S protector board? Much cheaper, fewer hassles, guaranteed to work, safe.

Comment: Could you recommend me an specific one, excuse me but I am new to battery management

Comment: https://www.batteryspace.com/pcbfor108v111vpack.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you can, put the whole thing into a a spice package like LT spice and simulate it. I would then ramp up the voltage and see how the over under voltage responds. Also put different resistive loads (and maybe current loads) on it and make sure the circuit voltages and currents behave normally. Also check the thermal performance (alt click on components in lt spice). Another thing to do would be to put a reverse voltage on it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I am starting to learn more about how to perform that simulation